# "Activation of network connection failed" popup continuosly showing up

Tags: wireless

I am getting a popup saying "Activation of network connection failed" continuously showing up.

I am connected via WiFi.

[image: desktop screenshot with small connection failed popup]

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the network switches indicated by [this tutorial](https://appuals.com/activation-of-network-connection-failed-in-linux/), then restart your machine and turn them enabled again.

In the end, restart your PC

(if your Ubuntu is running in a VM running on a "mother" OS - i.e. Windows -  then restart that OS, In the end turn on your VM again and )

and run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
```

If you cannot fix this, then just disable the "connect automatically" option for connection "ethernet enp0s8".

[image]