# Suppressing annoying connection failed messages

Tags: networking

I sometimes get annoying "*Connection Failed*" messages that I either cannot dismiss or that recur soon after dismissing them.  (see also for example this question ["Activation of network connection failed" popup continuosly showing up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132876/activation-of-network-connection-failed-popup-continuosly-showing-up)). How can I suppress these? I am not interested in solving the network issue. These messages often show up for my bad wifi while I have a wired connection or in other cases resolve themselves so quickly that there is no problem. I just want to get rid of these messages.

Also even if I can't suppress them how can I at least get rid of one that is there and is not responding to anything. (It has a cross but clicking it does not do anything.) I have tried selecting it with `sudo xkill` but it does not do anything to the pop-up window.

---

Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: You have not given a version of Ubuntu in your question, please add it to the question with edit. Not in comments. You say there are issues and you choose to ignore them, very strange. As far as hiding the messages which you have not included in the question there is not way to suggest how to suppress them. We do not have a clue what they are.